# Python Binance API Call list

Tags: python, binance

I'm a beginner.
I would like to get from Binance Api (`data = futures_get_open_orders()`) the data ["symbol"] ["price"] ["origQty"] and ["site"].
This is my previous attempt:

```
data = [{'orderId': 561756151, 'symbol': 'LINKUSDT', 'status': 'NEW', 'clientOrderId': 'x-40PTWbMIQT4J13S', 'price': '7.664', 'avgPrice': '0.00000', 'origQty': '0.10', 'executedQty': '0', 'cumQuote': '0', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'reduceOnly': True, 'closePosition': False, 'side': 'SELL', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'stopPrice': '0', 'workingType': 'CONTRACT_PRICE', 'priceProtect': 'false', 'origType': 'LIMIT', 'time': 1595666654269, 'updateTime': 1595666676102}]


if len(data) == 0:
    print("No Open Orders!")
else:
    print("Open Orders:")
    #price = (data("price"))
    price = (data["price"])
    print(price)
```

```
    price = (data("price"))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

    price = (data["price"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

In another scenario (also Binance API) I got it with `data.get("price")`
but it doesn't work here.

Please help me out a littl.

Comment: Here ``data`` is a list you need to access it with index ``data[0]['price']`` or iterate over it using a for loop.

Comment: An easier way to access these data is to store it in a python dictionary and then use for x in data: #whatever you want from within the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error. This error occurs when you try to call a non callable object. Instead of using `object()` use `object[]` and you are good to go.

Comment: That is not what is happening here

Comment: If the error says TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, this is exactly what happening here. Op did not show the actual code.